# How can i put condition with table JSON attribute

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I want to put conditions on the JSON attribute in the table but no luck. Please give me a solution that how can I put condition with JSON table attribute

This is my JSON data in the table

```
"products": {
    "id": 1,
    "key": "category"
    "categories": {
        "category_A": "John Quil",
        "category_B": "Ev R. Lasting",
        "category_C": "923117253207",
        "category_D": "Anne Thurium",
        "category_E": "Ginger Plant",
        "category_F": "Rose Bush"
    },
    "created_at": "2021-06-21T16:18:29.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-21T18:03:03.000000Z"
}
```

This is my controller code

```
$product = Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->where('categories->category_C', $request->category_C)->first();
```

I have also used these concepts but not working

```
Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->whereRaw('JSON_LENGTH(`categories`, \'$."category_C"\'), $request->category_C')->first();
Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->whereRaw('JSON_LENGTH(`categories`, \'$."category_C"\'), $request->category_C')->first();
```

```
Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->whereJsonLength('categories->category_C', $request->category_C)->first();
Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->whereJsonLength('categories->category_C', $request->category_C)->first();
```

Comment: All the documentation is here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses. Your code looks ok; what specifically isn't working? Sidenote, you don't need `::query()` before `where()`, `::where()` is fine :)

Comment: Thanks, @TimLewis is working, before was not working with the same condition I don't know what was issue

Comment: Might have been an issue with `$request->category_C`? That would be the thing that could change between requests... Regardless, glad you got it working 

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Product::query()->where('key', 'category')->where('categories->category_C', $request->category_C)->first();
```

Comment: Again, `Product::where(...)` is fine; you don't need `::query()` here; it's redundant 